# Why does not Vite watch work with server proxy

Tags: vuejs3, vite

I have a SpringBoot backend and a Vue3 frontend. I use Vite on frontend side. I would like to config proxiing from port 5173 to 7600 and to poll Windows filesystem in order to see changes as soon as possible. Without proxy watch is working on port 5173. But if I use proxy as well, I cannot see changes on port 7600. Without proxy I can do nothing, because backend is running on port 7600. Is it possible to config both proxy and watch?

Here is my vite.config.ts:

```
import { fileURLToPath, URL } from 'node:url'

import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue'

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [vue()],
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      '@': fileURLToPath(new URL('./src', import.meta.url))
    }
  },
  server: {
    watch: {
      usePolling: true
    },
    proxy: {
      '': {
        target: 'http://localhost:7600',
        changeOrigin: true
      },
    }
  }
})
```